# calculate the group of all biholomorphic group automorphisms of complex tori

Tags: lie-groups, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

My backgrand is complex geometry,but when I confront complex tori,I feel it is easier to consider it as a compact connected complex Lie group although I just know the definition of Lie group.
Let $X=\mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda$,where $\Lambda$ is the discrete subgroup of maximal rank in $\mathbb{C^n}$ whose entries $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ are of the form $x_i=a_i+b_i\sqrt{-1}(a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{Z})$.
I want to calculate the group of all biholomorphic group automorphisms $Aut(X)$.
Geometrically,it is the groups of isomorphisms as complex manifolds fixing zero.When $n=1$,it is intuitive that $Aut(X)=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.But when the dimension becomes higher，I feel difficult to set out to calculate $Aut(X)$.
I wonder if this problem is easier from the viewpoint of Lie group.Complex geometrical approach is also welcome!Thanks in advance!

Comment: The automorphism group of a 1-dimensional complex torus varies, depending on the lattice. The automorphism group can be either $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (this is for a general 1-dimensional torus), $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ for the lattice $\langle1,i\rangle$, $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ for the lattice $\langle1,\omega\rangle$ where $\omega$ is a 3rd root of unity. In general (dimension>1), the automorphism group will depend on the lattice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ ought to be isomorphic to $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}[i])$, where $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ denotes the Gaussian integers.  Note that this group is infinite for $n > 2$, since it contains $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

(I've made this answer community wiki in case someone else wants to add more information.)

Comment: If $\Lambda$ is the lattice of the complex torus, then $\mbox{Aut}(\mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda)=\mbox{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})\cap\mbox{GL}(\Lambda)$, where $\mbox{GL}(\Lambda)$ denotes the linear automorphisms of the lattice. This strongly depends on the lattice.

Comment: @RobertAuffarth Can you give me a reference to your statement,please?I'm interested in this problem.Thank you!

Comment: Sure, take a look at the first chapters of Birkenhake-Lange.

Comment: For $n=1$, you can find this in many introductory books on algebraic geometry, like for example Miranda's Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces